# Proguard returned with error code 1. See console java.io.IOException

Tags: android, eclipse, httpclient, proguard, androidhttpclient

While exporting my Android Application from Eclipse IDE, I am getting errors as below:

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient extends or implements program class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
Warning: there were 1 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
          You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will
          be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

**project.properties**

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt:proguard-google-api-client.txt

# Project target.
target=android-21
```

**proguard-project**

```
# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn javax.jdo.**
-dontwarn com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.**
-dontwarn org.ietf.jgss.**
-dontnote
```

I have added dontwarn and dontnote statements to proguard confing file with that I resolved few warnings but Not able to solve remaining issue.Please help me to solve this.Thanks you.

Comment: can you show the project properties file for proguard configuration?

Comment: see the edited question for property details @Opiatefuchs

Comment: :) , sorry, and please the proguard text file, sorry at the moment I forgot how the correct filename is..

Comment: now you can find the proguard details too @Opiatefuchs

Comment: You are using Eclipse for Android development?

Comment: yes at that time was using Eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the issue was due to library class `android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient` and `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient`, I added **-dontwarn** statements for both the library classes to proguard-project file. what I added is:

```
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.*
-dontwarn android.net.http.*
```

and I am done. Thank you all for helping out on this.

Answer (score 3):

You Just need to add below code to your project's **proguard-project.txt** file.

```
-dontwarn ["error package name or Error file path here"]
```

example as :

```
-dontwarn com.example.media.*
```

and if you have more(insane) errors coming, then just add

```
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
```

May be this helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to Your proguard-project file:

```
  -keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
  -dontwarn org.apache.http.*
```

Then come back if still errors exists.

Comment: Getting `proguard.ParseException:  Expecting java type before ';'` error on line `  -keep class org.apache.http.** { ; }`

Comment: Solved the parseException error by replacing `;` with `*;` but again getting same error as in question.

Comment: also after clean project?

Answer (score 1):

**please used comments before the given code bellow**
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt:proguard-google-api-client.txt

**In project.properties file**

Comment: used comments if your proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt:proguard-google-api-client.txt

Answer (score 0):

I also have faced this problem. Cleaning the project and exporting again should fix this.

Comment: I have tried this before asking here. Not working for me at all.